# Issue with $.when - success displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Hey guys I have the following code:

```
function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';
    var tag = $("#dialog-container");

    var promise1 = showUrlInDialog(url);
    var promise2 = sendUserfNotes();

    $.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(data1, data2) {

      tag.html(data1).dialog({
          width: '100%',
          modal: true
        }).dialog('open');
       $('#notes_msg').text(data2[0].the_notes)
    });
}
```

This right here works great...it will wait for the two functions to run after that than it will open up a window in JQuery UI - dialog the tag.html....  Than it will display the notes that are returned in the text-area field in that file.  This works great accept I keep getting success to display on the top left corner of my screen and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  If you could give me a hand I would appreciate it.

David

UPDATE:

I figured out what is causing it:

```
tag.html(data1).dialog({
              width: '100%',
              modal: true
            }).dialog('open');
```

I don't know why though?

When this opens the dialog window up, success the word is on the left hand side of screen.

Comment: Where do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqueryui dialog positioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304830/jqueryui-dialog-positioning)

Comment: @bfavaretto...I don't want it displayed at all.  I need to get rid of the success

Comment: This has nothing to do with positioning?

Comment: Sorry, I rolled my edit back. I'm not sure what you don't understand, the fragment you cited explicitly opens a modal window when both ajax requests are successful. If you don't want that, just remove (a) the `dialog()` calls, or (b) the whole `$.when` thing (if you don't want to do *anything* when both ajax calls complete).

Comment: No no I don't want THE WORD 'success' to show on my screen.....it pops up on the left hand side of screen?  I have no idea why.  It will only do that if I open the dialog inside the $.when function

Comment: Looks like your server is returning that. The `.dialog()` call is not "causing it", it's just displaying your server's response in a modal dialog. Again, if you don't want to display that, remove the `.dialog()` call. Or, if you want to display something else, change `tag.html(data1)` to `tag.html("whatever you want")`.

Comment: @bfavaretto I need to display that though?  So how do I get past that and I need it to open up within that $.when function

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I figured it out:

```
tag.html(data1[0]).dialog({
              width: '100%',
              modal: true
            }).dialog('open');
```

I just had to add the `[0]` to `data1`